# How to find a gtkwindow by title

Tags: gtk

I'm working on the Ubuntu. I'm writing an app to capture a gtkwindow screen shot. But now, I can't get the gtkwindow pointer by the window title. Is there way to find a gtkwindow by the title?

Answer (score 2):

Gtk has no API for doing this. You only get GtkWindow objects for windows you create yourself. You have to do it more low level and use xlib directly. First you must get the Display object for the your display (basically an object representing the connection to your Xserver and is needed because an Xclient can show windows on several Xservers at once). Use `gdk_x11_get_default_xdisplay()` to get the default screen if you don't have any other ide of how to get a certain screen. Then you get the root window with `DefaultRootWindow()`. To get a list of child windows use `XQueryTree()`. And to get the name of the window for comparison use `XFetchName()`. Note that windows in the context of X is not identical to what is perceived as windows. The window manager frames are windows (sometimes in multible levels) containing the actual application windows as children so `XQueryTree()` might need to be used recurively.

You might also be interested in [libwnck](http://developer.gnome.org/libwnck/stable/) which can simplify this a bit.